# Have trouble with sending data to db. Unsuccess request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Trying to push register data to db but server returns `error 500 (Internal Server Error)`,  I am  just training so dont know how to fix it here's my code. The browser that the problem is in query hook or route path but i cant find it

```
    const express = require('express')
const config = require('config')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const app = express()

const PORT = config.get('port') || 5000


app.use(express.json({extended:true}))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth.routes'))

async function start(){
    try{
       await mongoose.connect(config.get("mongoURL"),{
        useNewUrlParser:true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true,
        useCreateIndex:true,
       })
       app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`app has been started on port ${PORT}...`))
    }catch(e){
        console.log('server Error', e.message)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}

start()
```

this is my route (routes/auth.routes.js) Route should validate achieved data and save indo db. Validation working, but if i make real user it returns err 500

```
      const {Router} = require('express')
const User = require('../models/User')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const config = require('config')
const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator')
const router = Router()
router.post(
    '/register',
    [
        check('email', 'incorrect email').isEmail(),
        check('password', 'min 6 symb')
        .isLength({min:6})
    ],
 async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors:errors.array(),
                message:'incorrect data'
            })
        }
        const {email, password} = req.body   
        console.log(req)
        const candidate = await User.findOne({email})
        if(candidate){
            return res.status(400).json({message:'Already exists'})
        }

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12)

        const user = new User({email, password: hashedPassword})

        await user.save()
        res.status(201).json({message:'created'})

    } catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({message:'something goes wrong try again'})
    }
})
module.exports = router
```

config file maybe needs i dont know

```
     {
    "port":5000,
    "jwtSecret":"secret",
    "mongoUri":"mongourl/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
    
}
```

hook that should push data to server

```
import {useCallback, useState} from 'react'

export const useHttp = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    const request = useCallback( async(url,method = "GET", body=null, headers={}) => {
        setLoading(true)
        try{
          if(body){
              body = JSON.stringify(body)
              headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
          }
          const response =   await fetch( url, {method, body,headers} )
          const data = await response.json()
          if(!response.ok){
              throw new Error(data.message ||'something goes wrong')
          }
        setLoading(false)
          return data
         
        } catch (e) {
            setLoading(false)
            setError(e.message)
            throw e

        }
    },[])

    const clearError = useCallback(()=>setError(null),[]) 

    return {loading, request, error, clearError}

}
```

and page where it all must works

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { useHttp } from '../hooks/http.hook'
import { useMessage } from '../hooks/message.hook'


 const AuthPage = () => {
    const {loading,error, request, clearError} = useHttp()
    const [form, setForm] = useState({})
    const message = useMessage()
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setForm({...form, [e.target.name]:[e.target.value] })
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        message(error)
        clearError()
    }, [error])
    const registerSubmit = async()=>{
        try{
            const data = await request('/api/auth/register', 'POST', {...form})
            console.log('Data',data)
        }catch(e) {

        }
    }
return(
<>
<div className="input-field ">
                    <input onChange={handleChange}name="email" placeholder="put email" id="email" type="text" />
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field ">
                    <input onChange={handleChange} name="password"placeholder="put password" id="password" type="text" />
                    <label htmlFor="password">password</label>
                    </div>
<button onClick={registerSubmit} disabled={loading} className='btn black'>Register</button>
</>
)
}

Node server returns error 
       Error: Illegal arguments: object, number
[0]     at _async (/Users/user/first-nodeapp/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:214:46)
[0]     at /Users/user/first-nodeapp/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:223:17
[0]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[0]     at Object.bcrypt.hash (/Users/user/first-nodeapp/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:222:20)
[0]     at /Users/user/first-nodeapp/routes/auth.routes.js:33:45
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: What is the server error log?

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: thats all no more info

Comment: Thats the info on the browser, check the terminal where the express server is running

Comment: oh just now note message  Error: Illegal arguments: object, number
[0]     at _async (/Users/user/first-nodeapp/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:214:46)
[0]     at /Users/user/first-nodeapp/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:223:17
[0]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
[0]     at Object.bcrypt.hash (/Users/user/first-nodeapp/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:222:20)
[0]     at /Users/user/first-nodeapp/routes/auth.routes.js:33:45
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add t there so that it can be formatted and is readable...

Comment: Your `password` type is `object` !! Can you please console `password` before converting it into `hashedPassword` ?